# Does hardly precede the verb or follows it

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

On page 202 in English Grammar in Use (5th edition) by R. Murphy, it's written on section C that 'Hardly goes before the verb' but later at the end of the page one of the examples is 'She was very quiet. She said hardly anything'. How can these two distinct information be true at the same time?

Plus, is 'hardly' an adjective or adverb in the sentences above?

Comment: For a much broader illustration of the use of **hardly**, try :https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hardly    The answer is that in the sentence above, **hardly** is an adverb, describing how much/little she said.

Comment: Would you share your thoughts about the way the book in question teaches adj and adverbs?

Comment: Whenever you have doubts, it's worth googling the issue to see what other sources have to say about it.  There are numerous sites that deal with grammar.  From time to time, you may well find that there is disagreement over usage, or that certain books advocate eccentric ideas.

Answer (score 2):

*Hardly* can modify a verb, or a noun phrase - in either case it usually precedes the item it modifies.

With an intransitive verb, it can only modify the verb, so must precede it:

> He hardly spoke during the meeting.

Similarly with a transitive verb where the object is not scalable:

> I could hardly see him in the fog.

But where the object is something scalable, *hardly* can modify it:

> She said hardly anything.

The meaning is not substantially different from modifying the verb:

> She hardly said anything.

and in fact we often use this form even when logically it might make more sense to modify the object.

Comment: Yes - it must be adjectival in some contexts, as it is possible for it to exist in a sentence with no verb.  "How much does it cost?" "Hardly five pounds".

Comment: I wouold class it as adverbial even in that use, rather than adjectival.